# Chrome console backslash with numbers

Tags: google-chrome, console, numbers, escaping

Why is chrome console converting numbers preceeded by backslash to unicode or in some cases - to special characters like "\b, \t, \f" etc.? In case of \8 and \9 it is even returning just the numbers itself? What is the logic behind this?

You can test it by opening console in chrome and just typing strings.
Here are some examples:

```
"\0"  - outputs "\u0000"
"\1"  - outputs "\u0001"
"\2"  - outputs "\u0002"
"\3"  - outputs "\u0003"
"\4"  - outputs "\u0004"
"\5"  - outputs "\u0005"
"\6"  - outputs "\u0006"
"\7"  - outputs "\u0007"
"\8"  - outputs "8"        ???
"\9"  - outputs "9"        ???
"\10" - outputs "\b"       
"\11" - outputs "\t"       
"\12" - outputs "\n"       
"\13" - outputs "\u000b"       
"\14" - outputs "\f"       
"\15" - outputs "\r"       
"\16" - outputs "\u000e"       
"\17" - outputs "\u000f"       
"\18" - outputs "\u00018"      
"\19" - outputs "\u00019"       
"\20" - outputs "\u00010"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problably because `\8` and `\9` are [invalid octal escape sequences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Bad_octal) in javascript.

`\[0-7]`, `\[0-7][0-7]`, and `\[0-7][0-7][0-7]` are octal escape sequences, which is obvious at `\10` (octal) == [`\u0008` (hex/unicode)](https://unicode-explorer.com/c/0008) == `\b` (backspace).

For me, the strange thing is that `\18` is not treated as an invalid octal escape sequence, but as hexadecimal...